# Javascript library to compare 2 html string like freecodecamp

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a project where we have a compare the original code and code written by the user. The user can code and then on button click we have to compare the written code with original code.

I have both original and new code in string

originalHtml : `<html><body style='color:white;background:purple;'></body></html>`

newHtml : `<html>     <body style="background:purple;color:white;">  </body> .  </html>`

Here there are 3 things to keep in mind

1) White space (should not show the difference for white space)

2) `'` and `"` (should not compare quotes, both are valid in HTML)

3) Attribute order (should show difference only for missing attribute, ignore attributes order)

Any suggestions or alternative solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all of them to one uniform and compare them.
Example:

- remove all space, tab (with one space)
- replace all `'` to `"`
- sort attribute.
- and some rule you defined

Example cheerio to get attribute:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var yourString = `<html><body attr2='hi' attr1='hello' style='color:white;background:purple;'></body></html>`;
var $ = cheerio.load(yourString);
var yourAttrs = $('body')[0].attribs;
var sorted = {};
Object.keys(yourAttrs).sort().forEach(function(key) {
    sorted[key] = yourAttrs[key];
});
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Do you know how to sort the attributes?

Comment: @PiyushDhamecha what you actually tried searching for this? There are loads of NodeJS libraries for parsing HTML documents.

Comment: Is this code run in server Nodejs ? Try use cheerio

Comment: @Ｈｏｎｇａｒｃyes, its in Nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I have created a code pen for you, this will solve your problem.

https://codepen.io/bearnithi/pen/KEPXrX

```js
const textArea = document.getElementById('code');

const btn = document.getElementById('checkcode');

const result = document.getElementById('result');

let originalHTML = `<html><head>
<title>Hello  </title>
</head><body>
 <p class="hello"></p>
</body>
</html>`

btn.addEventListener('click', checkCode);

function checkCode() {
  let newHTMLCode = textArea.value.replace(/\s/g,"");
  
  let oldHTMLCode = originalHTML.replace(/\s/g,"");
  
  if(newHTMLCode === oldHTMLCode) {
    console.log(true);
    result.innerHTML = 'TRUE';
  } else {
    console.log(false);
    result.innerHTML = 'FALSE';
  }
  
}
```

```html
<textarea id="code">
  
</textarea> 
</br>
<button id="checkcode">Check Code</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but does it validate if attributes are not in order?

Comment: No i have not yet added the sorting alogrithm in it.